# Can't create table with "." "," "/" "-" in the table name

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Quick questin for OLEDB and creating a new table. In one part of the program I have a code that creates new table in database and the name of table is what user inserts into textbox. For regular words it all works ok, but when I try to add ".", ",","-" or "/" the program breaks down and it can't create the table.

Is there any way to enable creating tables with "-" or "/" in the table name? That possibility is pretty important

connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C_\\.....\\robnoknjigovodstvo1.mdb";
```

Table is beeing created after a button click

```
OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd4.Connection = konekcija;
            cmd4.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + opis + "(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), nazivMaterijala VARCHAR(50), jedMjera VARCHAR(50), kolicina FLOAT)";
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Where is the code used to create the table? and for which database?

Comment: @Steve added details in the question

Comment: This is for an Microsoft Access Database?

Comment: I typically replace all invalid characters to an underscore. Some DBAs frown on using invalid characters in Table Names.

Comment: @jpw yes, it's for access database

Comment: "That possibility is pretty important" - you really should reevaluate this. Just do some simple input validation on the textbox. Your database object names will be much easier to read and any code you write against them will be less error-prone.

Comment: Technical details aside, the idea of creating tables with names based on arbitrary user input just seems *wrong* to me somehow....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enclose the table name in square brakets

```
  cmd4.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + opis + "] (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ...."";
```

However keep in mind that [Microsoft discourages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826763) the use of special characters in table names.
I think that it is better for you and for your code to prepare a method that searches these special characters and replace them with something more easy to handle in future query. (Like an underscore)

```
string ReplaceSpecialChars(string inputName)
{
    char[] verbotten = new char[] { ' ','\'', '"','\'','@','`','#','%','>','<','!','.','[',']','*','$',';',':','?','^','{','}','+','-','=','~','\\' };

    int pos = -1;
    while((pos = inputName.IndexOfAny(verbotten)) != -1)
        inputName = inputName.Substring(0, pos) + '_' + inputName.Substring(pos+1);

    return inputName;

}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't help
I tried 

    cmd4.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test/test(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ...."";

to see is "/" really the problem and it didn't work that way either. So the "opis" is not the problem

Comment: @user2516578 The CommandText in your comment doesn't reflect the suggestion Steve made, it should look like: `"CREATE TABLE [test/test] (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ...." `

Comment: yes, in the end that did solved the problem

 I forgot to put "[]" in one more command that was in the same try/catch/finnally block, and when the program break down at the same point I thought it was the same problem

thanks for helo

Answer (score 1):

If this question relates to Microsoft Access as the provider in the connection string suggests, these are the rules for naming objects:

> Guidelines for naming fields, controls, and objects
>
> Names of fields, controls, and objects in Microsoft Access: Can be up
>   to 64 characters long. Can include any combination of letters,
>   numbers, spaces, and special characters except a period (.), an
>   exclamation point (!), an accent grave (`), and brackets ([ ]). Can't
>   begin with leading spaces. Can't include control characters (ASCII
>   values 0 through 31). Can't include a double quotation mark (") in
>   table, view, or stored procedure names in a Microsoft Access project.

And if you want to use any special characters or whitespace in the name you should enclose the identifier in brackets like `[name with space]` but even better would be to not use the problematic characters at all, but to replace them if possible.